# Need a formula in Google Sheets that will return the same value as an Excel formula

Tags: sorting, date, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula

I need a formula for Google Sheets that will work exactly like the following formula does within Excel.

Formula in Excel: `=@SORT(FILTER(B74:B80,E51=C74:C80,""),1,-1)`

Does anyone know what formula would do this please?

Currently I've used the following formula in Google Sheets but is returning all results, instead of just the largest date:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(B74:B80,E51=C74:C80),"")
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(B74:B80, E51=C74:C80), 1, 0), 1, 1)
```

or:

```
=MAX(FILTER(B74:B80, E51=C74:C80))
```